# Why does "CORS Anywhere" suddenly returns the error: "Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with"

Tags: node.js

I use "CORS Anywhere":
https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere

**Everything worked just fine until a few days ago.**

Now, every request I make returns the same error:

> Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with

for example:
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.instagram.com/adidas/

You can try for yourself, every request returns the same error.

I uploaded the code to my server and i still have the same problem.

Comment: Did you solve this problem eventually? Exactly the same thing is happening to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think CORS anywhere's owner got finally fed up with people abusing his service, kindly and freely provided for development purposes only:

[image]

Please see the related issue: https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/issues/301

> The demo server of CORS Anywhere (cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com) is meant to be a demo of this project. But abuse has become so common that the platform where the demo is hosted (Heroku) has asked me to shut down the server, despite efforts to counter the abuse (rate limits in #45 and #164, and blocking other forms of requests). Downtime becomes increasingly frequent (e.g. recently #300, #299, #295, #294, #287) due to abuse and its popularity.

EDIT: Turns out that I'm a few years too late, oh well, better late than never :D